# string matching with elastic search using regexp

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have a Document field "Address". and its mapping is

```
 "ADDRESS": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
```

And I want to apply regexp on that using elastic search query but after one word spacing it starts apply regexp on second word 
for example:

```
{
"ADDRESS": "Govindpuri Kolkata India "
},
{"ADDRESS" "Koli Badi India"
 }

**query:**
{
    "query": {
        "regexp": {
            "ADDRESS": {
                "value": "Govindpuri K",
                "flags": "ALL",
                "max_determinized_states": 10000

            }
        }
    }
}
```

after typing "Govindpuri[space]k" it throughs result address starts with K and i want govindpuri kolkata as a result.

Comment: what is your use case, regex queries are very costly, if you can provide sample docs and expected results, i can suggest better alternatives

Comment: You can also check https://opster.com/elasticsearch-glossary/elasticsearch-autocomplete-troubleshooting-guide/ for various implementation and consideration if trying to implement autosuggest

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja i have a 20 million address data and want a autocomplete on that data .....so the user can get a list of address according to its typing

Answer (score 0):

Text is split on white space and special characters and stored in index as separate tokens.

If you will use analyze api , you can see "Govindpuri Kolkata India" is split and stored as 3 tokens.

```
GET address/_analyze
{
  "text": "Govindpuri Kolkata India"
}

"tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "govindpuri",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "kolkata",
      "start_offset" : 11,
      "end_offset" : 18,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "india",
      "start_offset" : 19,
      "end_offset" : 24,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    }
  ]
```

To search on entire string you need to use [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/key) sub field which stores full text

```
GET address/_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "ADDRESS.keyword": {
        "value": "Govindpuri K.*",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "max_determinized_states": 10000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Regular expressions and wildcards are slower, above implementation can also be achieved using [match_phrase_prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) which has better performance

> Returns documents that contain the words of a provided text, in the
>   same order as provided. The last term of the provided text is treated
>   as a prefix, matching any words that begin with that term.

```
GET address/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "ADDRESS": "govindpuri k"
    }
  }
}
```